# Error with jQuery get of a CSV file

Tags: jquery, csv, get

Here is my relevant jQuery code:

```
$.get('sampleData.csv', function(data) {
    var lines = data.split('\r\n');
```

The first few line of the sampleData.csv file look like this:

> 2009,0,2,29.0000
>   2009,0,6,655.6200

I get 2 errors. 
On the first line of csv file I get the error

> syntax error

On the 2nd line of code I get the error

> data.split is not a function

What am I doing wrong?

**ETA** According to the firebug console, the responseText is the following:

> 2009,0,2,29.0000\r\n2009,...\r\n2011,10,30,494.3500\r\n

**ETA** I added an alert of the data before I try splitting it into lines, and I get the following:

> [Object XMLDocument]

Comment: What is the specific syntax error you're getting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you misunderstand what jQuery.get() is suppose to be used for.

From it's [doc page](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/), `"...Load data from the server using a HTTP GET request...."`

Doing a $.get() on a file will not get you that file's data into a structure that can be used. You have to request this through a server which will then provide the .csv data ... it should look something like the following

```
$.get('http://url.to.server.page',function(data){
    var dataStr = new String(data);
    var lines = dataStr.split('\n');
});
```

---

**EDIT::**
 Since you say the data is being 'loaded' properly, try this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UVELg/). It works just fine.

---

EDIT2::

Your last edit gave some interesting insight. When it pulls the .csv file, its converting it to a type of XML vs text. Try the following:

```
$.get('http://url.to.server.page',function(data){
    var dataStr = new String(data);
    var lines = dataStr.split('\n');
},dataType='text');
```

This should put the returning 'data' into the proper string format.

Comment: According to the firebug console, it appears to be retrieving the data correctly.

Comment: It seems like your first answer (misunderstanding jQuery get) is the correct one. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

jQuery code:

```
$.get('data.csv', function(data) {
  var lines = data.split('\r\n');
});
```

works until jquery version 1.5.
From version 1.5 callback function in get() method is passed "jqXHR" object, not "XMLHttpRequest" object.
Code can be changed to:

```
$.get('data.csv', function(data) {
  var lines = data.split('\r\n');
}, "text");
```

Then it will work.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

Answer (score 0):

Your almost there. Missing the final parenthesis and need a different split character.

```
$.get('sampleData.csv', function(data) {
var lines = data.split(',');
});
```

**Edit**

Ah you changed your CSV to two lines i assumed it was just one line seperated by commas not data seperated by new line also seperated by commas. The below I retested and worked fine for me.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">Jquery Reference or insert directly here </script>
</head>
<body>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    $.get('csv.csv', function(data) {
    // Split the lines
    var lines = data.split('\n');
    var i = 0;

    for(i=0; i<lines.length; i++)
    {
       alert(lines[i]);
    }

}); 

});
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

I just had that html file on my desktop with the csv you pasted in the same place.