# speedtest.net api

Tags: jquery, google-chrome-extension

I want to make a widget to display the user's most recent speed test results. Does speedtest.net have an api I could use? I tried making an ajax request to http://speedtest.net/csv.php?csv=1&ria=0&s=0 but got a cross domain error. I tried an iframe, but that just made it appear in downloads.

This is going to be in a Google Chrome extension so I can use the chrome api if necessary.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

speedtest.net is run by [Ookla and their Speed Test application](http://www.ookla.com/speedtest). Unfortunately they don't provide any public APIs for speedtest.net which you could use.

Although I doubt either of these meet your needs, they do provide [Speed Test Mini](http://speedtest.net/mini.php) and a [hosted reporting solution for their full Speed Test software package](http://www.ookla.com/speedtest) (which includes CSV exporting capabilities).

The reason you're unable to use AJAX is because Chrome will not allow JavaScript to perform cross-site requests unless the [`Access-Control-Allow-Origin`](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#access-control-allow-origin-response-header) response header is set in the response from speedtest.net to permit such a request.

In a Chrome extension, however, you can allow cross-origin requests by adding the URL to the permissions section of your [`manifest.json`](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/manifest.html#permissions) file. For example:

```
"permissions": [
  "http://*/"
],
```

You could then use a bit of jQuery to retrieve the CSV data as a string (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8186194/1166205)):

```
$.get('http://speedtest.net/csv.php?csv=1&ria=0&s=0', function(data) {
    var csv = new String(data);
    // do stuff with csv
}, dataType='text');
```

Comment: I have speedtest.net in the permissions. Using your code, I still get this error:
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://speedtest.net/csv.php?csv=1&ria=0&s=0. Origin chrome-extension://pjmjaebdfmbljffjkcgegpgocnkoembf is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Comment: Sorry, I haven't had time to work on this. I'll try tomorrow.

Comment: @Jack Tuck JSONP has to be supported on the server.

Comment: Speedtest Mini has been discontinued since June 30, 2017

Answer (score 2):

Try [MySpeed.today](https://myspeed.today).  It may work out.

Answer (score 1):

You can make cross-origin XMLHttpRequests in a chrome extension, **provided that** you've requested permissions for it.

In your [`manifest.json`](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/manifest.html#permissions) file, add the URI:

```
"permissions": ["http://speedtest.net/csv.php?*"]
```

See also: [Match patterns](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/match_patterns.html).

Answer (score 1):

Ookla does provide an [API](https://support.ookla.com/hc/en-us/articles/115002187768-Speedtest-Intelligence-Data-Extracts-API)

You need to get their API key. They also provide a sample Python script.

Comment: It's a paid feature, besides.

Comment: It look like this API is not for speed testing. It is just a tests data service

Answer (score 0):

Ookla is providing [Enterprise SDK](https://www.ookla.com/speedtest-sdk), you will need to request it.