# C# Downloading a file gives different result WebClient - Browser

Tags: c#, api, csv, webclient, speed-test

I have been trying to create a network-monitor like application.
To do this, I would like to use the speedtest.net api. The idea is simple, you download a csv file containing your best results. (http://www.speedtest.net/csv.php?csv=1&ria=0&s=0)

However, when I download this file with my regular browsers, I get this:
[image: Many results]
When I download it through the C# WebClient, I get this:
[image: No results]

Any ideas on how to resolve this?

Comment: You first execute a speed test with the browser then download this or you login to the site first and then download this, or you have an auth cookie and are already authenticated That's why the browser shows the results. Try opening a different browser and you should see the empty table as I did

Comment: Possible duplicate of [speedtest.net api](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10022711/speedtest-net-api)

Comment: You can google for getting the cookies for a specific Url with c# and an unmanaged API, I did that once

Answer (score 0):

I followed your link http://www.speedtest.net/csv.php?csv=1&ria=0&s=0 with a networkmonitor. The Http HEADER in the response has a field Content-length:103 and thats too short for the whole file.
So I think your service returns a wrong content length. The browser ignores this error, the C# WebClient does not ignore this error