# Speedtest Cli with flutter

Tags: flutter, command-line-interface, speed-test

It says here as **Use Speedtest in your programs by wrapping it in the programming language of your choice** in the official speedtest cli [site](https://www.speedtest.net/apps/cli). What does this mean? Can I use this results to generate in my flutter application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on [this forum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10022711/speedtest-net-api), I don't think you could do that.

But, you could use the open-source internet speed test [project](https://speed.measurementlab.net/) from M-Lab and Google. You could see the GitHub Repo [here](https://github.com/m-lab/mlab-speedtest).