# Highcharts not displaying in Firefox

Tags: javascript, csv, firefox, highcharts

I am using the following JavaScript Code to create a Highchart from a local csv file. This works correctly in Safari and Chrome (need to enable `--allow-file-access-from-files` for it to work in Chrome), however it does not work for Firefox for some reason. I have tried changing the value of `security.fileurl.strict_origin_policy` to false but that doesn't change the error or display the charts.

I get a JS "syntax error" for the csv file for ':1:1' which I assume is line 1 column 1. I don't understand why it works for 2 browsers and not for Firefox. I imagine it is something similar to Chrome where I have to enable access to local files but besides changing the `about:config` I'm not sure how to achieve this.

Any explanations or suggestions are appreciated.

```
 $.get(data, function(csv) {
      $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
          zoomType: 'x',
          type: 'column',
        },
        data: {
          csv: csv,
          lineDelimiter: "\n",
        },
        title: {
              text: 'CSV file data'
          },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Bytes'
            }
        }
      }); 
    });
```

Comment: It could be a localization issue, like firefox is set to en-us and chrome set to en-gb or something..if you're getting a syntax error then the file is being opened and read I would assume, so it's not likely to be a file-access issue is it ?

Comment: @secretsquirrel I really don't know to be honest, I thought it might be something similar to Chrome where you have to allow file access from local files. But I can't seem to get it to work. I found this link that someone else had this problem but I can't find a solution forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-csv-firefox-weird-syntax-error

Comment: @ Catherine ok see the answers to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8185912/error-with-jquery-get-of-a-csv-file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that adding "text" after `$.get(data, function(csv) {}` solves this issue for firefox. Not entirely sure why. It takes longer than Chrome or Safari to load but it does load successfully.

Provided you have enabled `--allow-file-access-from-files` it will work in Chrome and doesn't cause any changes in Safari.

```
 $.get(data, function(csv) {
      $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
          zoomType: 'x',
          type: 'column',
        },
        data: {
          csv: csv,
          lineDelimiter: "\n",
        },
        title: {
              text: 'CSV file data'
          },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Bytes'
            }
        }
      }); 
    }, "text");
```

Comment: See [API](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/#jQuery-get-url-data-success-dataType). Looks like Firefox requires strict `dataType` when loading files from filesystem.